# In angular 2 and ionic 2 *ngfor, if i click on any one element it reflect on all?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic2

If i am clicking on **playNote(note)** function but it change all **[name]="myIcon"** in ngfor loop.
I just want to change the clicked one...

**home.html**

```
<ion-item color="theme" class="note-block" *ngFor="let note of notes; let i = index" >
      <button class="action-btn" ion-button icon-left clear small (click)="playNote(note)">
        <ion-icon color="darker" [name]="myIcon"></ion-icon>
      </button>
</ion-item>
```

**home.ts**

```
myIcon: string = "play";


playNote(note){
    if(this.myIcon === "play"){
        this.myIcon = "pause"
    }
    else if(this.myIcon === "pause"){
        this.myIcon = "play";
    }
}
```

Comment: please take a look at my updated response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two possibilities :

First one, you can define myIcon like this

```
myIcon: string[] = [];
```

then

```
playNote(note){
    if(this.myIcon[note] === "play"){
        this.myIcon[note] = "pause"
    }
    else if(this.myIcon[note] === "pause"){
        this.myIcon[note] = "play";
    }
}
```

In template

```
<button class="action-btn" ion-button icon-left clear small (click)="playNote(note)">
        <ion-icon [name]="myIcon[note.id]?myIcon[note.id] : myIcon[note.id] = 'play'"></ion-icon> <!-- default value to play -->
</button>
```

Second one, create a wrapper component (list note) and single note component. All your single items will have different scope so you can use safely your method as it in the single item component :

```
playNote(note){
    if(this.myIcon === "play"){
        this.myIcon = "pause"
    }
    else if(this.myIcon === "pause"){
        this.myIcon = "play";
    }
}
```

<s>These are untested codes. Some adjustment may be required</s>
Here is a working plunker 
http://plnkr.co/edit/BOqB37AQkbySrzzDS5Vy?p=preview

**Edit** : Here is a quick fix 
http://plnkr.co/edit/SVy8IkHxnKCDb4yA52HO?p=preview

In this example, I use boolean

In template :

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let note of notes; let i = index">
     <h2>{{note.name}}</h2>
       <button class="action-btn" ion-button icon-left clear small (click)="playNote(note)">
         <ion-icon *ngIf = "!myIcon[note.id]" [name]="'play'"></ion-icon>
         <ion-icon *ngIf = "myIcon[note.id]" [name]="'pause'"></ion-icon>
       </button>
   </ion-item>
```

In component

```
myIcon: boolean[] = [];

playNote(note){
    this.myIcon[note.id] = !this.myIcon[note.id]
}
```

Comment: if i want to initiate myIcon with play value ... is it possible?

Comment: you can create a function to populate your array but initiate it in the template is more simple `[name]="myIcon[note] = 'play' "` (I suppose that note is a identifier, use instead note.id if it's an object)

Comment: yes its an object. so i used myIcon[note.id] ---  if i console its changing the myIcon value but in template its not changing....... :(

Comment: Did you adjust your method as well ? `if(this.myIcon[note.id] === "play"){
        this.myIcon[note.id] = "pause"
    }`

Comment: I am sure u can solve this problem but i am not able to explain the question correctly... i guess... whatever you suggested that makes sense but some where i am missing something...  See let me try... i have a play button on my template, so when i click it has to convert to pause but only for that current object... not for whole loop (*ngfor)......

Comment: please create a plunker, I'll see what I can do for you

Comment: You're welcome. I'll take a look on the first solution later if I got some time ...